# Is there any ambiguity about the supernatural in Sarah Water's The Little Stranger

Tags: sarah-waters, the-little-stranger

*The Little Stranger* is a gothic-style novel by Sarah Waters in which a fading aristocratic family appears to be haunted by a presence in their crumbling estate.

Minor spoilers for the book follow.

The initial signs of presence are easily interpreted with rational explanations. As the plot goes on, however, it becomes increasingly hard to assign the malevolent goings on to mere circumstance. Nevertheless, the ending appears ambiguous on the matter and critics are divided on whether this is valuable or disappointing.

However, it seemed to me that on at least one occasion, this ambiguity is resolved. When Faraday is walking in the garden with Mrs Ayres, we see the following paragraphs:

> I tugged down the blouse's collar and saw beneath it, on her bare skin, a scratch, quite deep, evidently freshly made, still rising, still beading red.
>
> 'What have you done?' I said in horror. 'How did you do this?' I looked over her gown for a pin or a brooch. I caught up her hands, examined her gloves. There was nothing."

The injury, then, has arisen spontaneously. Mrs Ayres blames it on the ghost and Faraday can find no alternative explanation. Since scratches do not arise by themselves, when reading I took this as confirmation of the supernatural nature of the haunting.

This fits with the novel's theme of male entitlement: Faraday always presumes he is correct in his rational perception and refuses to accept the testimony of the three women who live in the house. If they are, in fact, correct, it would re-enforce the toxic nature of his presumptions.

Has Waters, or any critic, or a close reading ever confirmed whether or not the author intended the reader to be certain one way or the other? If we are supposed to believe in the haunting explanation, why does Waters throw it back into doubt at the conclusion?

Comment: It's been a long time since I read it. What do you mean by "the ending appears ambiguous on the matter." Is it simply that the issue is never resolved, or is there something specific that happens that casts doubt on the supernatural explanation?

Comment: @PeterShor What I'm interested in is whether we can resolve if there is, or is not, a "supernatural" presence in the house. Betty's evidence - and the testimony of the Ayres family - suggests there is, whereas Faraday and his fellow doctors rationalise it all away. I can see your deleted answer and, for clarity, I'm less interested in the potential *nature* of the supposed entity than whether it is real, or a figment of the Ayres's imagination.

Comment: My deleted answer says that if the haunting was real, the book's ending is perfectly consistent, given that there is a good explanation for why the narrator is unreliable. So she's not actively "throwing it in doubt" at the conclusion. But if you're not content with minor evidence that the haunting is real, like the scratch referenced in your question, I suspect there's nothing more convincing in the book. (And I suspect the author intended it that way.)

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://www.goodreads.com/questions/312936-how-do-readers-interpret-the-ending-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I read the book, and I don't believe there's any absolutely undeniable evidence for the supernatural, so somebody who is determined to read this as a realistic novel can do so. However, as you cite in your question, there are a number of incidents in the book which are very hard to explain without assuming a supernatural cause.

You seem to think that in the ending of the book, the author throws doubt on the supernatural explanation. I don't believe that this is the case; I think that the ending is no more ambiguous than the rest of the book. The narrator (as opposed to the author) does reject the supernatural explanation at the end, but I think this is a case of an unreliable narrator—there is a very good reason he rejects the supernatural explanation, which I can't reveal without giving you massive spoilers for the book.

One question, which is a mild spoiler:

> Did you figure out who the poltergeist is (assuming there is one)?

And another question, which is a massive spoiler:

> Given that the narrator is the poltergeist, and that he has destroyed everything he loves, isn't it completely understandable that he would refuse to admit it to himself.

Finally, if you admit the supernatural explanation, then the ending of the book ties everything up neatly, and also ties in with an overall theme about the decline of the British aristocracy after WWII. ([See Jo Walton's review here](https://www.tor.com/2010/07/09/a-man-and-a-house-sarah-waters-the-little-stranger/), which also hints at the above spoilers.) If you only admit the realistic reading, it seems to me that the entire book is a much more pointless narrative.